# Multithreaded Web Server Flow diagram

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a Multi-threaded web server with 1 scheduling thread,1 queuing thread and n execution thread in C++ and it is a homework problem. I am not asking the code. I have created a flow for the server. Can you tell me if the flow is correct or not ?

```
main()              //queuing thread
{
     define sockets
     create scheduling thread
     create queue of n execution threads   //n execution threads
     accpet connection infinetly
     {
          insert the request in a queue 
     }
 }

 scheduling thread         // scheduling thread
 {
      job = take each request from queue ( FCFS or SJF)
      take 1 thread from queue of execution threads and assign the job request
  }
```

Is this flow for the problem correct? I just need the direction.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @cHao. I won't "abuse" flags for that :) Will simply delete :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot...1 more question.When assign the job I will have mutex for locking and unlocking the thread.Will the conditional variable will be same for all the threads or different for each thread?

Comment: You will want a unique mutex or locking mechanism for each thread.